# SDL 8.1 on windows 2012 r2 in azure arc extended support?

Tags: sdl-tridion, azure

I have SDL8.1 in Windows2012R2. Now I am going get extended support for my windows using Azure ARC. Will it impact my SDL8.1?

Answer (score 3):

SDL Web 8 Cumulative Update 1 (8.1) has already been retired. Extended Security Updates for Windows Server 2012 R2 in Azure does not directly impact Tridion Sites. Since the version of Tridion Sites (8.1) has already been retired, you will not receive any Hotfixes or support from R&D for this version in case of any issues. There are no guarantees in this regard, and RWS support will be unable to assist you as this is not a supported version.

I recommend considering an upgrade to the latest version of Tridion Sites to ensure compatibility with the latest Windows OS, database, and Java versions, and to receive ongoing support.